# How to assign values in a dynamic structure parameters

Tags: c

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
  char nom[30], prenom[20];
  int age;
} ITEM;

//and I have a function where I am entering the info as follow:

void Lire(ITEM **items, int *nb_items)
{
    int i,j = 0, novalida = 0;
    ITEM *temp;
    printf("*** Entrer les donnees et taper . pour terminer\n\n");

    for (i = 0; TRUE; i++) {

        temp = (ITEM *) realloc(*items, ((*nb_items + 1) * sizeof(ITEM)));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Il n'y a pas de memoire! \n");
            exit (0);
        }
        *items = temp;
        printf("> nom    : ");
        scanf("%s", **items[i].nom);
```

and I got the the error:

```
 request for member ‘nom’ in something not a structure or union
 scanf("%s", **items[i].nom);
```

Then I want to know if I should assign the values to dynamic structures the same way I go with normal structures.

Comment: This is c code as far I can see, why did you tag your question c++?

Comment: Sorry it is my first time

Comment: The real answer to your question would be to avoid too many levels of indirection, because such mistakes are then easy to make. You have several solutions for this: 1st solution encapsulate items and nb_items in a structure, then change your function to take a pointer to that structure. 2nd solution, use a linked-list instead of a dynamic array.

Comment: Thanks Etienne, in this concrete exercise I must use a dynamic array, I tried as you told me below but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some parentheses, because the operator `.` has a higher precedence than the operator `*`, you are doing `**(items[i].nom)` whereas you want `(*items[i]).nom`.

The error is telling you that you are trying to use the operator `.` on `items[i]`, which has type `ITEM *` (not a structure or union).

Your example should be:

```
scanf("%s", (*items[i]).nom);
```

Comment: i think thats to many pointer derefernce (*items[i]).nom is needed. (**item is a ITEM not an array of ITEM)

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like

```
scanf("%s", items[i]->nom);
```

You have a pointer to pointer of ITEM, so `items[i]` accesses a pointer to ITEM, then you use `->` to access the fields of the structure.